# Trying to swap my old domain for my new one

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I purchased the "real" domain name for my website and I'd like to re-direct all traffic that was going to the old site, to the new site.

Here's the scenario: I currently have http://www.wrestlestats.com, but I want to start having everyone use http://www.wrestlestat.com (note without the "s" on the end).

All of google (and I'm assuming all other search engines) return my results for the old site (with the "s").

From what I've [read here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Example_HTTP_response_for_a_301_redirect), everything is just telling me to put a 301 re-direct either on the page (`html` `meta`), or in a web.config, or in the `Page_Load` code in the controller.

My problem is, these are assuming the old "code" is completely separate and sitting on a different server. No, I have 2 domains pointed to the same site/code. If I place the re-direct in the `html` `meta` section, then my page will just keep looping. I'm running `ASP.NET Core` so I don't have a web.config.
What to do for people running `ASP.NET Core`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in 2 steps ---

1. Configure new domain (instead of old one)to your site.
2. Use Forward Domain from your domain control panel with the option of path forwarding.

Forward:-

> http:-//www.wrestlestats.com       **>**       http:-//www.wrestlestat.com

Comment: I have forwarding turned on with my domain provider already. When users go to old site, it still shows that in the address bar...that's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: which one provider you use.

Comment: just use path forwarding

Comment: i think you use forward with masking option also, that why your domain masked in to actual one

Comment: Register.com is my domain provider. I'll check with Register.com to see if they have a "path forwarding" option...

Comment: Hmm, so I just checked on register.com again. I don't see anything that specifies forwarding with masking...but digging deeper, I wonder if I found the issue. I have BOTH domains CNAME records pointing to my Azure website, while the "S" version of the site ALSO has the basic forwarding turned on. Could that be the issue? Remove the CNAME record(s) (of the "S" version), and then let the forwarding take over?

Comment: if problem persist, tell me detail on skype @ Zigri2612

Comment: That did it. Having both sites setup with the CNAME was the problem! Thanks Zigri! Step 1 of your solution is what I should have followed better.